# Change css style of Angular Material Data Table

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using mdDataTable to display data retrieved form Server. Is there a possibility to change the css class of `mdt-row`? If I try to add a class, mdDatatable overwrites it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your own css file, you can override the css by explicitly targetting the angular md classes, like this:

```
.mdt-row {
  {overridesettingname}: {newsetting};
}
```

But I'd be careful because that overrides site-wide. You can override just a single page by targeting a parent element on the page, like:

```
.{mypageclassname} .mdt-row {
  {overridesettingname}: {newsetting};
}
```

Another note, make sure YOUR css file is loaded AFTER the angular css file(s).

Comment: Thank you! I have the same problem with the mdt-column.... I try to add a span which dinamically translate, but it overwrites it.... 
            <mdt-column align-rule="right"><span translate="status"></span></mdt-column>

how can I solve it?

Comment: Make sure your css file is loaded AFTER the angular files. If it is, then use Chrome/Firefox dev tools to determine which property it being loaded last.

Answer (score 0):

[image: DataTable client version]
You can explore the classes and ids for the element in the developer tool, It is easy to add style for all elements, Here I've added sample styles you can keep added as you wish. Hope it helps.

```
 .mat-table {
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 700px;
      }

 .mat-header-cell .mat-sort-header-sorted {
        color: #0A0A0A;
      }

 md-pagination-wrapper {
        width:auto !important;
    }

 md-row:nth-child(even){
      background-color:#EDF1F5;
      }

 md-row:nth-child(odd){
      background-color:#FDFDFB;
      }
```